# Access variable from another class (in C++)

Tags: c++, class, inheritance, function-definition

This may be a really easy question but... here it goes. (Thanks in advance!)

I am simplifying the code so it is understandable. I want to use a variable calculated inside another class without running everything again.

**source.ccp**

```
#include <iostream>
#include "begin.h"
#include "calculation.h"
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    beginclass BEGINOBJECT;

    BEGINOBJECT.collectdata();
    cout << "class " << BEGINOBJECT.test;

    calculationclass SHOWRESULT;
    SHOWRESULT.multiply();

    system("pause");
    exit(1);
}
```

**begin.h**

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

#ifndef BEGIN_H
#define BEGIN_H

class beginclass
{
    public:
        void collectdata();
        int test;
};

#endif
```

**begin.cpp**

```
#include <iostream>
#include "begin.h"

void beginclass::collectdata()
{
    test = 6;
}
```

**calculation.h**

```
#include <iostream>
#include "begin.h"

#ifndef CALCULATION_H
#define CALCULATION_H

class calculationclass
{
    public:
        void multiply();
};

#endif
```

**calculation.cpp**

```
#include <iostream>
#include "begin.h"
#include "calculation.h"

void calculationclass::multiply()
{
    beginclass BEGINOBJECT;
    // BEGINOBJECT.collectdata(); // If I uncomment this it works...
    int abc = BEGINOBJECT.test * 2;
    cout << "\n" << abc << endl;
}
```

Comment: You can use a static member or singleton.

Comment: Don't use static member or singleton. Learn how to return things from functions, and how to pass things to functions.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Simply define member function `multiply` as

```
void calculationclass::multiply( const beginclass &BEGINOBJECT ) const
{
    int abc = BEGINOBJECT.test * 2;
    cout << "\n" << abc << endl;
}
```

And call it as

```
int main()
{
    beginclass BEGINOBJECT;

    BEGINOBJECT.collectdata();
    cout << "class " << BEGINOBJECT.test;

    calculationclass SHOWRESULT;
    SHOWRESULT.multiply( BEGINOBJECT );

    system("pause");
    exit(1);
}
```

Comment: Thank you! It solves the problem in my code but I have trouble understanding the "( const beginclass &BEGINOBJECT ) const" part. Can you explain it?

Comment: @ramen The first const means that the reference point to an object of type beginclass that is constant and may not be changed in the function. The second const means that the function does not changes the object for which it was called that is the object SHOWRESULT itself will not be changed.

Comment: Sorry I'm having another doubt. If in the member function `multiply` it is calculated an array (lets say) `yxz`, then how can I use it in other class again? In normal conditions I would put in `public: int** yxz; void calculationclass::multiply();` and it could be "extracted"... Can you give me another tip to solve this `int** yxz` need? Thank you for your patience.

Comment: @ramen I am sorry I have not understood what you mean. You may ask one more question here with a detailed description of the problem.

Comment: In **calculation.h** if I try to add an integer (to simplify, forget the array I said before..) like this: `class calculationclass { public: int yxz; multiply( const beginclass &BEGINOBJECT ) const; }` and then on **calculation.cpp** if I want to use, for example `void calculationclass::multiply( const beginclass &BEGINOBJECT ) const { yxz = 88*BEGINOBJECT.test; }`. yxz is not recognized and therefore this new value gets stuck inside the class... (Hopefully I made myself clear. It is hard through a comment.) Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are looking for some kind of lazy evaluation / caching technique whereby a value is calculated the first time it is requested then stored to return it subsequently without having to reevaluate.

In a multi-threaded environment the way to achieve this (using the new standard thread library) is by using `std::call_once`

If you are in a single-threaded environment, and you just want to get a value out of a class, use a getter for that value. If it isn't calculated in a "lazy" fashion, i.e. the class calculates it instantly, you can put that logic in the class's constructor.

For a "calc_once" example:

```
class calculation_class
{
   std::once_flag flag;
   double value;

   void do_multiply(); 
   double multiply();
public:

   double multiply()
   {
       std::call_once( flag, do_multiply, this );
       return value;
   }
};
```

If you want `multiply` to be const, you'll need to make do_multiply also const and value and flag mutable.

Answer (score 0):

In your code `beginclass` has no explicit constructor, hence the implicitly defined default constructor will be used, which default constructs all members. Hence, after construction `beginclass::test` is either `0` or uninitiliased.

What you appear to be wanting is to avoid to call `beginclass::collectdata()` more than once. For this you would want to set a flag that remembers if `beginclass::collectdata()` has been called. The member function which returns the data then first checks this flags and, if the flag was not set, calls `beginclass::collectdata()` first. See also the answer by CashCow.

Comment: `beginclass::test` will be uninitialized in OP's code.